# Magic Urn Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

ADDENDUM: First off, thank you all for your insightful answers to this weekend, fun problem, and especially Mark L Stone for his initial comment. I'm probably missing the point in some of the answers, in which case, please change them slightly so that I see it and can happily accept one. But, I guess the issue that I'm interested in is not so much how to solve the problem, or how some answers are nonsensical, but **How can it be that even though the equations that I used to solve the problem (and remember I didn't know the answer was going to be  3R/3B at that point) yield the correct answer even with the inclusion of an impossible scenario (2 pairs of red)?**

The Wall Street Journal has a [new section with math questions](http://blogs.wsj.com/puzzle/2015/09/18/math-quiz/). Today's question was open for discussion with posts by readers. So, in this regard, I presume it is fair to also discuss it here among a generally more expert audience. If this reasoning is faulty, just let me know and I'll erase the question.

> Your friend tells you: This is a remarkable urn. It contains only red
>   and black balls. If you reach in and take one ball at random, there’s
>   an equal chance of drawing red or black. So you might think that if
>   you instead take two at random, it’s 50/50 that your balls will match.
>   Well, you’d be wrong—but if they do match, and then you reach your
>   other hand in and take two more, your chances of matching a second
>   time are 50/50! How many balls in your friend’s urn (before you take
>   any out)?

Like a good number of people who still remember the basics of combinations and permutations, I followed this reasoning:

We start off with equal numbers of `red` and `black` balls ("equal chance of drawing red or black"), let's name this number $n$. After the first round you may have gotten `two red` or `two black`("but if they *DO* match, and then..."). Let's go with red, i.e. you have drawn `two reds`. You started with equal numbers or red and black or $2n$ balls in the urn, and after drawing the first pair, you have $2n-2$ with $n-2$ red balls remaining in the urn, and $n$ black balls.

They tell us that the chance of repeating the experiment and getting a second pair remain $0.5$ ("...your chances of matching a second time are 50/50"). So $0.5$ should be the probability of drawing a `second pair of red balls`, plus the probability of getting a `pair of black balls`:

$$0.5 = p(2R|\text{after Red pair})+p(2B|\text{after Red pair})= \frac{{n-2\choose 2}}{{2n-2\choose2}} + \frac{{n\choose 2}}{{2n-2\choose2}}$$

The answer turns out to be $n=3$ for a total of $6$ balls in the urn ($3$ Red and $3$ Black). Yet this makes it physically impossible for us to draw `two red balls` on the second round.

What am I missing?

In other words, we get the right result (see comments); however, we can't go back and "verify" that we got the correct answer, because when you go back to the equation above and plug in $3$ into the $n$'s, we get:

$0.5 = = \frac{{1 \choose 2}}{{4\choose 2}} + \frac{{3\choose 2}}{{4\choose 2}}$, and ${1 \choose 2}$ makes no sense. It's probably the way math is telling us that we can't draw `two pairs of red balls` with only 3 red balls available. If this is true, it is really cool in a wonderfully circular fashion: we got the right answer including an impossible premise in the equation, in such a way that the result prompts us to modify the equation that generated the answer in the first place!

We would have gotten the same result with:

$0.5 = p(2B|\text{after Red pair})= \frac{{n\choose 2}}{{2n-2\choose2}}$ despite the fact that we didn't know at first that the scenario of drawing two pairs of  `red balls` was impossible.

Comment: "Yet this makes it physically impossible for us to draw two Red balls on the second round."  So what?  With one red and 3 black,  ${3\choose 2}$ out of  ${4\choose 2}$ possibilities are both black, i.e., the same color, which is 50/50. I think the question is meant to be interpreted as the 2nd pair match each other, not that they match the first pair - perhaps this is where you are "going wrong".

Comment: @MarkL.Stone It is just puzzling to get the right answer (6 balls) even when I have included in the equation the probability calculus of a scenario that is physically impossible: drawing a second pair of red balls after having drawn a first pair of red balls.

Comment: You missed out the case when the first fair is a black ball. So the left side should have a factor of $\frac{1}{4}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: using the 6 balls (3 red and 3 black) what is the probability of drawing two of the same color (i.e., the first step in the question). Words + math is helpful. thx.

Comment: we don't know the result is 6 until we get it. but we can get it using a formula that includes a physical impossibility as you suggest. that makes it interesting to me.

Comment: @AntoniParellada Can you take a look at my edited answer?

Comment: @rightskewed I looked at the version control edit 4 hours ago. Your answer is really good, although that perhaps due to my own limitations, I'm still missing a convincing response to my query. Let me leave the question open for a little while longer, and I'll be sure to accept your answer if things stay the same. Ty

Comment: @AntoniParellada Do you see solcing the linear equation is bounded by the constraint $n \geq 4$ and hence any solution should pass through this filter to be a 'solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing?
>   How can it be that even though the equations that I used to solve the problem (and remember I didn't know the answer was going to be 3R/3B at that point) yield the correct answer even with the inclusion of an impossible scenario (2 pairs of red)?

$$0.5 = p\,(2\,R\,|after\,Red\,pair)+p\,(2\,B\,|after\,Red\,pair)= \frac{{n-2\choose 2}}{{2n-2\choose2}} + \frac{{n\choose 2}}{{2n-2\choose2}}$$

holds only for $n-2 \geq 2$ because $n\choose r$ is a non zero for $n \geq r$, so the solution $n=3$ to this equation is bounded by this constraint: $n \geq4$, which implies there is no solution.

### Solution

P1, P2 represent the two pairs drawn.

Scenario1: {P1: RR, P2: BB}

Scenario2: {P1: RR, P2: RR}

Scenario3: {P1: BB, P2: RR}

Scenario4: {P1: BB, P2: BB}

$$0.5 = P(P2=BB|P1=RR) + P(P2=RR|P1=RR) + P(P2=RR|P1=BB) + P(P2=BB|P1=BB)$$
$\implies$
$$ 0.5 = 2*\big(P(P2=BB|P1=RR) + P(P2=RR|P1=RR) \big)$$
$\implies$
$$ \frac{1}{4} = \frac{n\choose 2}{{2n-2}\choose 2} + \frac{{n-2}\choose 2}{{2n-2}\choose 2}$$
$\implies$
$ 2n^2-7n+9 =0$

I get no solution for $n$

Comment: You have to check the special cases where $n-2<2$. E.g. $n=3$ is a trivial solution. Your argument shows that there are no other solutions.

Comment: I meant n=3, as in 3 red balls and 3 black ones.

Comment: But, $n=3$ is not a solution for the *corrected version* of equation. OP's equation ignores Scenario3,4

Comment: I guess the way that you would solve this problem is: 1) Derive the solution OP has derived 2) Verify that it doesn't work for all cases, e.g. $n=2$ and $n=3$. Try it for the trivial cases and see that you get a solution. Your argument serves the purpose of excluding other solutions. I am not sure if (and how) you would create a general solution that covers all cases by using combinations in your argument, though it may well be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You miss that for n<4 this:
$$0.5 = p\,(2\,R\,|after\,Red\,pair)+p\,(2\,B\,|after\,Red\,pair)= \frac{{n-2\choose 2}}{{2n-2\choose2}} + \frac{{n\choose 2}}{{2n-2\choose2}}$$
does not hold.

First, for $n=1$ the problem makes no sense, because you cannot take 2 balls and then 2 more balls.

For $n=2$ or $n=3$, $p\,(2\,R\,|after\,Red\,pair)=0$ rather than $\frac{{n-2\choose 2}}{{2n-2\choose2}}$, so your formula should be

$$0.5 = p\,(2\,R\,|after\,Red\,pair)+p\,(2\,B\,|after\,Red\,pair)=\frac{{n\choose 2}}{{2n-2\choose2}}$$

which holds for n=3 but not for n=2.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be formal but I figured:
\begin{align}
\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{(2n-2)(2n-3)} + \frac{(n)(n-1)}{(2n-2)(2n-3)} &= .50  \\[10pt]
\frac{(n-2)(n-3)+(n)(n-1)}{(2n-2)(2n-3)} &= .50
\end{align}
Solving for $n$, QED $n=3$.

So it starts with 3 of each color, i.e., 6 balls total.

Comment: the OP might benefit more from your answer if you explain the steps

Comment: I believe this is the motivation: Assume 1st 2 balls red.  Prob of the next two being red is the expression to the left of the + sign.  Prob of the next two being black is the expression to the right of the + sign.

Answer (score -1):

Let $n$ be the number of balls. Then solve:
$$
\left[\frac{\frac n 2 }{n-2} \right] \left[\frac{\frac n 2 - 1}{n-3} \right] = \frac 1 2
$$